# Is 'when' better than 'where' here?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

In a [blog](https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/types-of-camera-shot-angles-in-film/#:%7E:text=Our%20first%20camera%20angle%20is%20the%20eye%20level%20shot%2C%20and%20this%20is%20when%20your%20subject%20is%20at%20eye%2Dlevel.) about camera shots, there is such a sentence:

> Our first camera angle is the eye level shot, and this is **when** your subject is at eye-level.

If I were the author, I would use 'where' instead of 'when'. Is there any reason why the author uses 'when' instead of 'where' here? Is 'when' better than 'where' here?

Comment: "When" picks out a particular point in time, so it makes sense if you're going through a series of shots; and shots happen one after another in time. But "where" would be just as good. Often there is more than one valid word and no real reason for choosing one over another.

Comment: **When** seems really wrong. A time is not even *implied* by "angle."